# Why $\varphi_n f_n\rightharpoonup\varphi f$ and $\varphi_n g_n\rightharpoonup \varphi g$ in $L^p$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ open, bounded with Lipschitz boundary.

I have a theorem that says that:

> If $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ in $L^p$ and $v_n\to v$ in $L^{p'}$ then $u_nv_n\rightharpoonup uv $ in $L^1$ where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p'}=1.$

Now I have function $f_n\rightharpoonup f$ and $g_n\rightharpoonup g$ in $L^p$ and that $\varphi_n\to \varphi$ in $L^\infty $.

Why the theorem above tell us that $\varphi_nf_n\rightharpoonup \varphi f$ and $\varphi_n g_n \rightharpoonup \varphi g$ in $L^p$ ? There is something I don't understand here.

Comment: Is there any distinction between the conditions on $f_n$ and $g_n$, or have you written the same question twice?

Answer (score 0):

There is an isometric embedding $L^\infty\to B(L^p)$ given by $\psi\mapsto (f\mapsto \psi\cdot f)$. It is a general statement that if you have a Banach space $X$ and a a norm convergent sequence of operators $A_n$ in $B(X)$ and a weakly convergent sequence $f_n\in X$ that then $A_nf_n$ converges weakly.

To do it let $h\in X^*$ and let $A$ be the limit of $A_n$, $f$ the limit of $f$:

$$\langle h, A_n f_n-A f\rangle=\langle h,(A_n- A) f_n\rangle+\langle h,A( f_n-  f)\rangle = \underbrace{\langle h,(A_n- A)f_n\rangle}_{(1)} +\underbrace{\langle A^* h, f-f_n\rangle}_{(2)}$$
Now term $(2)$ converges to zero, since $f_n$ converges weakly to $f$. Term $(1)$ can be bounded by
$$(1)≤\|h\|\,\|A-A\|\,\|f_n\|$$
if we see that $\|f_n\|$ is a bounded sequence we find that $(1)$ must also converge to zero. Well $f_n$ can be viewed as a sequence of functionals $X^*\to\Bbb C$ so that $f_n(h)$ converges for any $h\in X^*$, this means $$\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}|f_n(h)|<\infty$$
for any $h\in X^*$ by application of Banach Steinhaus you find that $\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}\|f_n\|<\infty$.

Comment: question has nothing to do with weakly convergence !   $u_n v_n$ is the product of two functions, and it defers from $\langle  u_n , v_n  \rangle$.

And moreover it is solved by applying  holder inequality (the $L^{\infty} $ version)

Comment: For sure $u_n v_n$ and $\varphi_n f_n$ refer to products of functions. However $\rightharpoonup$ is the symbol usually used to refer to weak convergence of a sequence. $\varphi_n f_n\rightharpoonup \varphi f$ iff for all $h\in L^{p'}$ you have $\int h^*\varphi_n f_n\to \int h^*\varphi f$.